# How can I output a odoo 8 datetime field without time on a qweb report?

Tags: xml, report, odoo-8, odoo, qweb

I want to output a odoo 8 datetime field in the localization format but without time.

I extended the `t-field` with the option `hide_time`.
Is there a simpler built-in solution?

Answer (score 5):

You could try specifying a format in `t-field-options`, like this:

```html
<span t-field="object.datetimefield" t-field-options='{"format": "MMMM d y"}'/>
```

just adjust the format as you want.

Comment: This doesn't seem to preserve localization choices.

Comment: Ups, I didn't noticed about it. Maybe this could help : https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/how-output-a-odoo-8-datetime-field-without-time-on-a-qweb-report-67948

Answer (score 4):

I have just faced this issue and now it's possible to do it in an easy way. This way shows only the date without the time in addition to keep the respective format lang of the date according to the user who printed the report.

```
<p t-field="o.your_datetime_field" t-field-options='{"widget": "date"}'/>
```

**Warning:** the quotes of `t-field-options` must be exactly like I wrote, otherwise, that line won't work.

Hope it helps in the future to anyone who needs this.

Comment: This is easily the simplest and most flexible option. Works great in Odoo 9. Thanks!

Comment: In Odoo 17, I need to change `t-field-options` to `t-options`, so the code will be like this

<p t-field="o.your_datetime_field" t-options='{"widget": "date"}'/>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formatLang`, `<t-esc="formatLang(o.your_datatime_field,date=True)"/>`

but you would need to override the report, as in this sample code:

```
################# 

import time

from openerp.report import report_sxw
from openerp.osv import osv



class QuotationPrint(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
        super(QuotationPrint, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
        })
        self.context = context


class quotation(osv.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.sale.quotation_template'
    _inherit = 'report.abstract_report'
    _template = 'sale.quotation_template'
    _wrapped_report_class = QuotationPrint
```

Source: https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/how-output-a-odoo-8-datetime-field-without-time-on-a-qweb-report-67948

Answer (score 0):

You can use QWeb options (t-field-options). For example:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-center report-field">
    <span t-field="ph_id.image_date" t-field-options='{"format":"d MMMM y"}'/> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
<span t-esc="time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y',time.strptime(object.datetimefield,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))"/>
```

Original Date field:

> 01/15/2017 10:41:01

Output Date field:

> 01/15/2017

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the `t-field-options` is not working, instead I use `t-options`.

```
<span t-field="o.date_approve" t-options="{'widget': 'date'}" />
```

the output will be like this : `09-Jun-21`